# Prove uniformly continuous $f(x)=1/x$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Consider the function $f : (0, 1] → R$ defined by $f(x) = 1/x$.

Prove that, for any $0 < r < 1$, f is uniformly continuous on $[r, 1]$.

I was trying to use the theorem if $f$ be continuous on [a,b] then $f$ is uniformly continuous. But I don't know how to relate and explain closed interval use the given $0< r < 1$.

Comment: Do you see that $[r,1]$ is also a interval "like" $[a,b]$ and $f$ is continuous on $[r,1]$?

Comment: yes I know, but I don't know how to relate 0 < r < 1

Comment: Well once you fix a $r$ then $[r,1]$ is a compact interval and $f$ is continuous on $[r,1]$ as i said hence $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: It is just the range of values of $r$ that you need to prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous over $[r;1]$

Comment: I totally understand, but the interval keeps change. so how to prove f on a  variable interval  continuous?

Comment: Just show that for an *arbitrary* value of $r$ in $(0;1)$ that $f$ is uniformly continuous over $[r;1]$.  (Not some particular value; *any* arbitrary one.)

Comment: so can I use [r,1] is the subset of natural domain of f to prove this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$, you need to find a $\delta(\epsilon)$ such $|x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

Let $x,y\in[r,1]$ then $|f(x)-f(y)| = |\frac1x-\frac1y|=|\frac{y-x}{xy}|\le|y-x|\frac1{r^2}=|x-y|\frac1{r^2}<\epsilon$

Let $\delta=\epsilon*r^2$, and that concludes your proof.

Comment: i use [r 1] is subset of R and then f is uniformly continuous on R and then f is uniformly continuous on [r,1] since [r,1] is subset of R.  Is the way correct ?

Comment: Since the function is only defined from domain $(0,1]$ then no, however it is uniformly continuous for all $a,b > 0$

Comment: Why are you allowed to say $\frac{1}{xy} \leq \frac{1}{r^{2}}$ exactly?

Edit: Nevermind, I get it - since $r$ is the lower bound then $\frac{1}{r}$ is the largest possible value for both $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{y}$.